# How does a Pageable request works?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I have a Pageable request which query for about 1.6 millions documents and each request limit the response to 1000 documents. The query use an index... Well at least it should... I'm using `db.currentOp()` to look for the request that takes a while to process. When I launched the query (yesterday at 01:00PM) it used the index for each portion of 1000. But it seems that at some point he decided not to use it anymore... And I can't figure out why...

I also have a `command` operation for the same query and it is using the index.

```
{
        "desc" : "conn7758",
        "threadId" : "1012",
        "connectionId" : 7758,
        "client" : "10.10.10.3:64670",
        "clientMetadata" : {
                "driver" : {
                        "name" : "mongo-java-driver",
                        "version" : "unknown"
                },
                "os" : {
                        "type" : "Windows",
                        "name" : "Windows Server 2008 R2",
                        "architecture" : "x86",
                        "version" : "6.1"
                },
                "platform" : "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_73-b02"
        },
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : 119588895,
        "secs_running" : 1299,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(1299666014),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "thingsplay.data",
        "query" : {
                "count" : "data",
                "query" : {
                        "device" : "S000110",
                        "topic" : "INPUTS/COIL1000",
                        "date" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2015-08-08T06:00:00Z"),
                                "$lt" : ISODate("2018-06-14T11:28:08.369Z")
                        }
                }
        },
        "planSummary" : "IXSCAN { device: 1, topic: 1, vhost: 1}",
        "numYields" : 81449,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : "r",
                "Database" : "r",
                "Collection" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(162900)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(81450)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(81450)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The request is still running... and I think it will be for a couple of hours.
Here is the last operations that is running :

```
{
        "desc" : "conn7758",
        "threadId" : "1012",
        "connectionId" : 7758,
        "client" : "10.10.10.3:64670",
        "clientMetadata" : {
                "driver" : {
                        "name" : "mongo-java-driver",
                        "version" : "unknown"
                },
                "os" : {
                        "type" : "Windows",
                        "name" : "Windows Server 2008 R2",
                        "architecture" : "x86",
                        "version" : "6.1"
                },
                "platform" : "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_73-b02"
        },
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : 120813021,
        "secs_running" : 134,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(134586683),
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "thingsplay.data",
        "query" : {
                "find" : "data",
                "filter" : {
                        "device" : "S000110",
                        "topic" : "INPUTS/COIL1000",
                        "date" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2015-08-08T06:00:00Z"),
                                "$lt" : ISODate("2018-06-14T11:28:08.369Z")
                        }
                },
                "projection" : {

                },
                "skip" : 1124000,
                "limit" : 1000
        },
        "numYields" : 8445,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : "r",
                "Database" : "r",
                "Collection" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(16892)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(8446)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(8446)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have the operation of the first operations that went well but you can see here that it doesn't use the index.

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "thingsplay.data"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "device" : 1,
                        "topic" : 1,
                        "date" : 1
                },
                "name" : "device_1_topic_1_date_1",
                "ns" : "thingsplay.data",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "device" : 1,
                        "topic" : 1,
                        "vhost" : 1
                },
                "name" : "device_1_topic_1_vhost_1",
                "ns" : "thingsplay.data",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

Comment: hi @Phoste, can you post the o/p of the explain plan from the following query: 
                 db.data.find({"device" : "S000110",
                        "topic" : "INPUTS/COIL1000",
                        "date" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2015-08-08T06:00:00Z"),
                                "$lt" : ISODate("2018-06-14T11:28:08.369Z")
                        }).explain("executionStats")

Comment: I can give you the explain plan without the executionStats since I'm running the same request for almost a day and it is still not finished.

Comment: The question is kind of broad and probably could instead be asked as *"How can I improve paging performance?"* instead. The `"skip" : 1124000,` line really should tell you exactly what is wrong here. Advancing the cursor like that takes time. If your actual 'intent' is always to be requesting the "next" page and then the "next" after that and not to "jump immediately" from page 20 to page 100, then there are indeed better ways to do it. But rather than an analysis of explain plans, this really needs you to explain the purpose you are doing this for instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm simply trying to get all the datas to export them in a json (I don't have access to mongoexport sadly..) The problem is that when I don't use Pageable my java program is running out of memory. What are the other way that I could use to improve my request ?

Comment: You don't need paging to export data. Iterate the cursor - retrieve a batch of documents, export them, free memory, repeat till cursor exhaust.